# Unable to send POST json request to restful api using Postman

Tags: json, rest, post, jersey, postman

I have a **RESTful** api as follow :

```
@Path("/entity")
public class EntityService {

    @GET
    @Path("/create")
    public Response createEvent(){
        return Response.ok("Entity created successfully").build();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testPost(Book book){
        System.out.println(book.toString());
        return Response.ok("Testing Post").build();
    }

    /**
     * Book have an id and name
     */
    public class Book {
        public String id;
        public String name;

        public Book(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + ", " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to send GET request to localhost:8080/entity successfully using POSTMAN.

But don't know how to send POST request.
I have made request using postman as shown in image.

[image: Request]

And I got this response

[image: Reponse]

Comment: Do you have a JSON provider? If not, let me know what Jersey version you are using, and I will see if I can help you find the right one to use.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your dependencies, I see you have the core Jackson dependencies. Jackson core alone isn't enough though. You need the Jackson JAX-RS JSON provider. This is included in

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also get rid of all the Jackson dependencies you currently have. The above will pull them in (you don't want versions to conflict).

Then you need to configure Jersey to use Jackson by adding the POJO mapping feature configuration switch, in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
       ...
</servlet>
```

Comment: One more thing I needed to do to make it work is:

put a empty constructor in class Book, so that object can be constructed using Json.

Comment: Yeah I didn't catch that. But I'm sure Jackson gave you a pretty clear message on what you needed to do :-)